# Weird javascript scoping issue

Tags: javascript, scope, sinon

I am facing  weird (to me) javascript scoping issue as described below. Appreciate any pointers

Test 'successful manual commit to Kafka' succeeds
Test 'failed manual commit to Kafka' fails with message 'Expected false to be true' for (mqClient.commit.called).to.be.true assertion

```
describe('samplelistener tests', () => {
  let sandbox
  const mqClient = { on: sinon.spy(), send: sinon.spy(), commit: sinon.stub() }

  it('successful manual commit to Kafka', () => {
    samplelistener.start(mqClient, {}, log)
    const handler = mqClient.on.getCall(0).args[1] // get the message event handler
    // call the samplelistener handler
    handler('randomtopicname', exampleMessage)
    expect(mqClient.commit.called).to.be.true // eslint-disable-line
  })
  it('failed manual commit to Kafka', () => {
    mqClient.commit = sinon.stub().throws()
    samplelistener.start(mqClient, {}, log)
    const handler = mqClient.on.getCall(0).args[1] // get the message event handler
    // call the samplelistener handler
    handler('randomtopicname', exampleMessage)
    expect(mqClient.commit.called).to.be.true // eslint-disable-line
  })
  it('failed manual commit to Kafka check 2', () => {
    mqClient.commit = sinon.stub().throws()
    samplelistener.start(mqClient, {}, log)
    const handler = mqClient.on.getCall(0).args[1] // get the message event handler
    // call the samplelistener handler
    handler('randomtopicname', exampleMessage)
    expect(mqClient.commit).to.throw(Error) // eslint-disable-line
  })

}

//sampleListener.js
const start = (mqClient, sampleConfig, log) => {
  mqClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        mqClient.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sure it's related to *scope*?

Comment: I'd rather say its related to your stubs.

Comment: If it `thows`, then would it be called? I would expect that you instead confirm that it did, in fact, throw an error and not just check to see if it was called.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced you actually call that callback. Or maybe you do but that *does* count as `commit` being called even if it throws an error. But I might be wrong. I've added the `sinon` tag, since I don't know the library well enough to know what it should do in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think its because of the way sinon works, I tried failure test case 2 and it worked.